# Como matar o processo automaticamente com Popen?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou executando um processo paralelo em python:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['python',path, title, uid])
```

O programa demora +- 1 minuto para terminar e executa normalmente. O processo gera um PID que consigo capturar: `process.pid`. Em um exemplo ele gerou o `PID 29058`. Tenho outro programa que irá manusear esses PID e verificar qual acabou atraves da função:

```
 def check_pid(pid):                                                             

  try:                                                                        
      os.kill(pid, 0)                                                         
  except OSError:                                                             
      return False                                                            
  else:                                                                       
      return True
```

Que também funciona normalmente.

Porém mesmo que meu programa que executei no `Popen` termine, e eu tenho total certeza que isso acontece. O processo no Ubuntu ainda continua executando o processo, sem consumir memoria e nada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu programa principal o qual eu chamo o primeiro comando acima é um servidor Bottle que não irá finalizar a não ser que eu queira. Quando eu mato o processo do servidor Bottle este processo de `PID 29058` também morre. O que quero saber é se há algum parametro que passo no Popen que faz o processo morrer automaticamente quando terminar e não ficar parado dessa forma?

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem o objeto criado pela chamada a `Popen` (na variável `process`, no exemplo que você deu), e detectar que a tarefa do processo foi concluída, basta chamar o método `wait` nesse objeto.

Em outras palavras: chame `process.wait()` depois que a tarefa estiver terminada.

Já que você está chamando um processo externo a partir de uma aplicação Web, no entanto, há outras dicas sobre caminhos a seguir:

Você poderia usar `ProcessPoolExecutor` no módulo `concurrent.futures` - isso permitiria que você tivesse um pool de processos externos fixos - e o módulo concurrent.futures se encarrega em reutilizar os processos que já executaram a sua tarefa e deixa-los prontos para a próxima.

A outra forma, exige repensar mais a arquitetura, mas é como se costuma fazer esse tipo de tarefa em "produção" em sistemas grandes: envolve usar o [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). O Celery é um framework que conecta diferentes processos em execução através de filas, mas isso é feito de forma quase transparente: você faz o que parece ser uma simples chamada de função em Python, o celery coloca os parâmetros numa fila externa ao processo, e um processo coordenado pelo celery, externo, mas que pode compreender inclusive o mesmo arquivo ".py" do programa que chama a função é que executa a chamada. Esse processo externo é um "worker" - e pode tanto estar no mesmo servidor que sua app Web, como em qualquer outra máquina da rede (permitindo assim a distribuição da carga de trabalho).

Comment: Meu servidor não pode esperar este processo terminar para continuar executando, meu unico controle do que está sendo executado e verificar se o processo com o PID está sendo executado.

Comment: Eu aumentei a resposta com o "one obvious way" usado hoje em dia para esse tipo de tarefa: usar o celery. MAs a ideia de chamar o `wait`seria depois que você detectasse que o processo externo cumpriu a tarefa, não enquanto ele está processando.